# What Interface Toolkit is being recommended for Ubuntu on Nexus7/Mobile Devices?

Tags: application-development, gui, interface, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I understand this is a may be a very premature question given that the current build is for testing Ubuntu Core, but I have just bought a Nexus7 to join in with this Ubuntu on mobile adventure and can't help wanting to start writing some apps!

I haven't really dabbled with either GTK or QT for touch apps yet and, having seen that Ubuntu TV is using Nux, I wondered what people on AskUbuntu-land would recommend.

Hope someone out there know this!
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended toolkit for ubuntu phone is Qt(c++ and qml) and html5, you can read about it here:

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/