# How to make and application for Ubuntu phone OS in QT creator?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, qt-creator

I want to develop and application for Ubuntu Phone os. How to do this in QT creator? Is it really possible to create an app for ubuntu phone os? or is does the Ubuntu phone apps made in the same way as in computer? I want answer for this. I just want to know that if there is any  special format or something which support Ubuntu phone os. So my question is that What is the format for apps to be installed in Ubuntu phone os?

Comment: IMO this question is too broad and can be answered in the documentation Fabby gave you (as a start) If or when you have a problem or have a specific question ask a new ...

Comment: @bodhi.zazen      If you feel the answer provided is a good start, (and I agree), shouldn't this question be re-opened to help others with the same question?

Comment: open/closed does not change the visibility of the answer. I still think the question is too broad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Interface Toolkit is being recommended for Ubuntu on Nexus7/Mobile Devices?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207650/what-interface-toolkit-is-being-recommended-for-ubuntu-on-nexus7-mobile-devices)

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [tutorial](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official Ubuntu Phone developer page](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/developers):

> Going native
>
> The Ubuntu SDK includes everything you need to create your own scopes, repurpose your web/HTML5 content and develop native apps.
>
> - QtCreator IDE (2.8.1) with improved device detection and management

So [start here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/)

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask